# DomException - Program execution stopped at line 2087 in prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, domexception

Suddenly, when I was working on my project and running it, the execution stopped as it was loading in Firefox. I get an Invalid Character Error.
I thought I might have caused the problems myself with the last changes in my code. So I restored my last backup of the project. But the problem remains.
I have also started the project in Chrome, but the same problem occurs.
I have put a breakpoint at the first line of my javascript-code, but the execution stops before my code is beeing run.
I have no idea of how to recover from this error situation. 
I really hope someone can help me, please ...

[Error situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU5IR.png)

Comment: Which version of PrototypeJS are you using? Its hard to tell from the screenshot. The latest version is 1.7.3 and there are new improvements in the Github repo.

Comment: I have 1.7.3.
Today I just commented away this prototype.js, and used standard javascript commands instead of observe and stopobserving. This seemed to solve the problem. But I can't understand what caused it. 
It has worked until now.

Answer (score 0):

I started to wonder if the change could be that I by a mistake, and lack of experience, could have turned on stop at every error or warning situation.
And, that was the problem. On the picture there is a pause button. I had pressed it without paying attention.

[Mystery solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW3zM.png)